# powershell cannot change directory if path contains [ whereas dos command can

Tags: powershell, special-characters, cd

I don't understand why I cannot in PowerShell go into a folder with `[]`, for example

```
cd c:\test\[demo]
```

whereas I have created in PowerShell with

```
md [demo]
```

and I can actually `cd` with DOS command.

So what can I do if I want to navigate in this folder from PowerShell ?

Comment: [DOS and cmd are very different](https://superuser.com/a/1411173/241386), don't use `dos` when using cmd

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cd` in PowerShell is an alias to [`Set-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location?view=powershell-7.2) which receives a `-Path` by default if no option is specified. Almost all PowerShell commands that deal with files like `Get-ChildItem`, `Get-Acl`... use the [FileSystem Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/About/about_FileSystem_Provider?view=powershell-7.2) and has `-Path` as a wildcard pattern where `[]` has special meaning. You'll need to escape those special characters like this

```
 cd '`[demo`]'
```

But cmdlets that receives wildcards also have `-LiteralPath` and that's the correct way to do

```
cd -LiteralPath [demo] # Or
cd -L [demo]
```